# INNER JOIN Number Range Lookup on VARCHAR

Tags: sqlite

So im wondering if its possible for SQLite to understand number ranges.

I want to be able to have a range such as "25-30" and lookup "27" to see if it falls within that range.
The issue is that the range will contain some text beforehand such as "Alice 25-30"

An example of what Id be looking to achieve can be seen in Table3 of this link:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=483f62c5fbf13998659cd5f7ebbb3ce9

More than happy for solutions that can break the string at the first number, but still keep the number so

`Alice | 25-30`

Not

`Alice | 5-30` (ive seen this suggested before :D)

**To actually create Table 3 ill be using either INNER or LEFT OUTER JOIN not just Re-creating the table but was speedier to do this**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a join of the 2 tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (`ID`, `Age`,'Age Range') 
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Age, t2.`Age Range`
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Age + 0 BETWEEN `Age Range` + 0 
                  AND SUBSTR(`Age Range`, INSTR(`Age Range`, '-') + 1) + 0
```

SQLite performs implicit conversions of strings to numbers when they are used in expressions with numeric operations like `+0`, so what the query does is to compare `Age` to the 1st and the 2nd part of `Age Range` numerically.
Note that `+ 0` would not be needed in `ON t1.Age + 0 BETWEEN` if you had defined `Age` as `REAL` which makes more sense.
Change the `INNER` join to `LEFT` join if you want the row from `Table1` inserted to `Table3` even if there is no matching `Age Range`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=68643318849217ecb14f65a3bcb8f5dd).
Results:

> | ID | Age | Age Range |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 30 | 25-30 |
> | 2 | 40.5 | 31-45 |